# Android Development - Can somebody help me explain the error when starting the app - RN 0.60.4

Tags: android, react-native, x86-64, apple-m1

**UPDATE:**

If you are trying to update your old react-native project:

- Create a new project and put your codes from previous project to that one
- May sound really exhausting, but this is more sane to do than updating
- Also use Android Studio when debugging, it tells you the error

Typescript React Native, you can easily select a working version of typescript and react-native
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-template-typescript

-------------- ============ -----------------

**3 things**

- Please help me to understand the logcat.
- I want to determine how to include libc.so in the package
- Is it necessary to upgrade react-native?

**Version and issue**

- I'm working on a react-native 0.60.4
- The app is running but not crashing upon open.

  - It display blank canvas, and do not continue to display a thing.

**Logcat when starting the app**

Updated Log: Aug 24, 2022

```js
08-23 07:12:35.355   496  2468 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=au.com.company.store/com.zeta.MainActivity bnds=[37,892][238,1206]} from uid 10152
08-23 07:12:35.356   496   530 D EventSequenceValidator: inc AccIntentStartedEvents to 2
08-23 07:12:35.356   496   514 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-23 07:12:35.358   496  4228 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-23 07:12:35.365   496   496 W ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } U=0: not found
08-23 07:12:35.365   496   496 W RemoteAppPredictionService: could not bind to Intent { act=android.service.appprediction.AppPredictionService cmp=com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiPredictionService } using flags 67108865
08-23 07:12:35.374   496   530 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 135634846; UID 10170; state: DISABLED
08-23 07:12:35.374   496   530 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 135754954; UID 10170; state: ENABLED
08-23 07:12:35.374   496   540 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 143937733; UID 10170; state: ENABLED
08-23 07:12:35.374   301   301 D goldfish-address-space: claimShared: Ask to claim region [0x1f97ac000 0x1fa114000]
08-23 07:12:35.407   290   290 D Zygote  : Forked child process 4961
08-23 07:12:35.408   496   540 I ActivityManager: Start proc 4961:au.com.company.store/u0a170 for pre-top-activity {au.com.company.store/com.zeta.MainActivity}
08-23 07:12:35.411  4961  4961 I any.store: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-23 07:12:35.421  4961  4961 I any.store: Unquickening 12 vdex files!
08-23 07:12:35.423   366   401 I adbd    : jdwp connection from 4961
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_10 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_6 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_8 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_9 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_4 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_5 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_11 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_7 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_2 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_3 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_10 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_6 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_8 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_9 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_4 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_5 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_11 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_7 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_2 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.426   496  2468 W InputReader: Device virtio_input_multi_touch_3 is associated with display ADISPLAY_ID_NONE.
08-23 07:12:35.569   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.570   496  3586 I system_server: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
08-23 07:12:35.572   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.585   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.587   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1800
08-23 07:12:35.602   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.604   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.619   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.620   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1800
08-23 07:12:35.635   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.636   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.651   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.653   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1800
08-23 07:12:35.668   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.670   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.685   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.686   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1800
08-23 07:12:35.697  4961  4961 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-23 07:12:35.698  4961  4961 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-23 07:12:35.702   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.703   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.711  4961  4987 I TetheringManager: registerTetheringEventCallback:au.com.company.store
08-23 07:12:35.715   496  3586 D CompatibilityChangeReporter: Compat change id reported: 136274596; UID 10170; state: ENABLED
08-23 07:12:35.718   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.720   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1800
08-23 07:12:35.724  4961  4999 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
08-23 07:12:35.726  4961  4996 W zzd     : Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
08-23 07:12:35.735   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.736   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.746  4961  4961 W zzd     : Application name is not set. Call Builder#setApplicationName.
08-23 07:12:35.749  4961  4961 D isEnabled: No perf enable meta data found in manifest.
08-23 07:12:35.750  4961  4961 I FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
08-23 07:12:35.751   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.753   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1800
08-23 07:12:35.755  4961  5003 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
08-23 07:12:35.757  4961  5003 I FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
08-23 07:12:35.757  4961  5003 I FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
08-23 07:12:35.760  1682  1682 D BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
08-23 07:12:35.760  1682  1682 D BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
08-23 07:12:35.764  4961  4961 I CrashlyticsCore: Initializing Crashlytics 2.6.8.32
08-23 07:12:35.767  4961  5014 I any.store: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
08-23 07:12:35.767  4961  4961 I CrashlyticsInitProvider: CrashlyticsInitProvider initialization successful
08-23 07:12:35.768  4961  5014 I any.store: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
08-23 07:12:35.768   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.771  4961  5014 I any.store: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
08-23 07:12:35.771   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.774  4961  4961 D SoLoader: init start
08-23 07:12:35.774  4961  4961 D SoLoader: adding system library source: /vendor/lib
08-23 07:12:35.774  4961  4961 D SoLoader: adding system library source: /system/lib
08-23 07:12:35.774  4961  4961 D SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~rjemURxDW_5fz2rjUjygYw==/au.com.company.store-Y8UwC7zGmO2RU5oJeOcjBw==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 D SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/au.com.company.store/lib-main flags = 1]
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib flags = 2]
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/~~rjemURxDW_5fz2rjUjygYw==/au.com.company.store-Y8UwC7zGmO2RU5oJeOcjBw==/lib/arm64 flags = 0]
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 D SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/au.com.company.store/lib-main flags = 1]
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/au.com.company.store/lib-main
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 I fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/au.com.company.store/lib-main
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/au.com.company.store/lib-main
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 D SoLoader: init finish: 4 SO sources prepared
08-23 07:12:35.775  4961  4961 D SoLoader: init exiting
08-23 07:12:35.785   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.787   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1800
08-23 07:12:35.790  4961  4994 I FA      : App measurement is starting up, version: 16250
08-23 07:12:35.790  4961  4994 I FA      : To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
08-23 07:12:35.790  4961  4994 I FA      : To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
08-23 07:12:35.790  4961  4994 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app au.com.company.store
08-23 07:12:35.793  4961  5020 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
08-23 07:12:35.793  4961  5020 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
08-23 07:12:35.794  4961  5020 D libEGL  : loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
08-23 07:12:35.798  4961  4961 D FirebasePerformance: Creating a new Non Verbose Session: c559b4856337410ba1ef5a89752e4432
08-23 07:12:35.798  4961  4961 D FirebasePerformance: Creating a new Non Verbose Session: 8d0b3b824c2f49c9819159fa130a4645
08-23 07:12:35.802   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : validate: layer 17 CompositionType 1, fallback
08-23 07:12:35.804   302   409 W EmuHWC2 : No layers, exit, buffer 0xb4000073da7b1260
08-23 07:12:35.809  4961  4961 D SoLoader: About to load: libjscexecutor.so
08-23 07:12:35.809  4961  4961 D SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so found on /data/data/au.com.company.store/lib-main
08-23 07:12:35.811  4961  4961 D SoLoader: Loading lib dependencies: [libfb.so, libreactnativejni.so, libjsc.so, libjsinspector.so, libfolly_json.so, libglog.so, libc++_shared.so, liblog.so, libc.so, libm.so, libdl.so]
08-23 07:12:35.812  4961  4961 D SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
08-23 07:12:35.812  4961  4961 D SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/data/au.com.company.store/lib-main
08-23 07:12:35.813  4961  4961 D SoLoader: Loading lib dependencies: [libc++_shared.so, liblog.so, libdl.so, libandroid.so, libc.so, libm.so]
08-23 07:12:35.813  4961  4961 D SoLoader: About to load: libc++_shared.so
08-23 07:12:35.813  4961  4961 D SoLoader: libc++_shared.so found on /data/data/au.com.company.store/lib-main
08-23 07:12:35.814  4961  4961 D SoLoader: Loading lib dependencies: [libc.so, libdl.so]
08-23 07:12:35.814  4961  4961 D SoLoader: About to load: libc.so
08-23 07:12:35.814  4961  4961 D SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/data/au.com.company.store/lib-main
08-23 07:12:35.814  4961  4961 D SoLoader: libc.so not found on /data/app/~~rjemURxDW_5fz2rjUjygYw==/au.com.company.store-Y8UwC7zGmO2RU5oJeOcjBw==/lib/arm64
08-23 07:12:35.814  4961  4961 D SoLoader: libc.so not found on /vendor/lib
08-23 07:12:35.814  4961  4961 D SoLoader: libc.so not found on /system/lib
08-23 07:12:35.862  1682  1682 D BoundBrokerSvc: onBind: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
08-23 07:12:35.862  1682  1682 D BoundBrokerSvc: Loading bound service for intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.measurement.START pkg=com.google.android.gms }
08-23 07:12:35.886  4019  4061 I Dialer  : OmtpVvmCarrierCfgHlpr - OmtpEvent:CONFIG_STATUS_SMS_TIME_OUT
08-23 07:12:35.886  4019  4019 I Dialer  : RetryPolicy - discarding deferred status: configuration_state=4
08-23 07:12:35.887  4019  4019 I Dialer  : VvmTaskExecutor - no more tasks, stopping service if no task are added in 5000 millis
08-23 07:12:35.890  4019  4019 I Dialer  : VvmTaskReceiver - task received
08-23 07:12:35.890  4019  4019 I Dialer  : VvmTaskReceiver - TaskExecutor already running
08-23 07:12:35.890  4019  4019 I Dialer  : Task.createTask - create task:com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask
08-23 07:12:35.890  4019  4019 I Dialer  : RetryPolicy - retry #2 for com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask@c816a00 queued, executing in 5000
08-23 07:12:35.890  4019  4019 I Dialer  : VvmTaskExecutor - com.android.voicemail.impl.ActivationTask@c816a00 added
08-23 07:12:35.890  4019  4019 I Dialer  : VvmTaskExecutor - minimal wait time:5000
08-23 07:12:35.890  4019  4019 I Dialer  : VvmTaskExecutor - sleep for 5000 millis
08-23 07:12:35.901   345   345 E Layer   : [Surface(name=Task=25)/@0xe790fb0 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
08-23 07:12:35.901   345   345 E Layer   : [Surface(name=Task=1)/@0x72c81a9 - animation-leash#0] No local sync point found
08-23 07:12:35.923   496   507 W System  : A resource failed to call release.
```

Comment: That error means either you're missing a library (libjsc.so) either for all builds, or for the particular ABI of Android that you're attempting to build.  Without that library, it will not run.  I'd make sure you didn't accidentally delete it from your project, and that you're building/running a supported ABI.

Comment: Thank you @GabeSechan for your quick response. Can you give me a hint where should i be looking at?

Comment: I installed the NDK, compiled the apk.
See updated Logcat above